# php _get_id puts null's in database

Tags: php

I have this php script:

```
private function _insert_options($veh_id,$id,$lang,$option,$price='',$cur='',$extra){
    global $db;

    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `".TBL_OPTIONS."` SET `veh_id`='%d',`opt_id`='%s',`lang`='%s',`text`='%s',`price`='%d',`cur`='%d',`extra`=%s",
    $veh_id,
    mysql_escape_string($id),
    $this->_get_id(TBL_LANGUAGE,'lang',$lang),
    mysql_escape_string($option),
    mysql_escape_string($price),
    $this->_get_id(TBL_CURRENCY,'cur_symbol',$cur),
    ($extra ?$extra :'NULL')
    );
    //echo '<br>insert: '.$query;
    $db->insert($query,__FILE__,__LINE__);
    //echo '<br>veh id '. $db->insert_id();
}
```

Problem is, when scirpt could not find "en" text in XML, script puts in "language" table some strange values. Like id= 255234, name= NULL and lang is empty.

Language table consist id,name and lang fields.

XML file has lines:

```
<option_price unit="LTL">1932</option_price> 
  <option_text lang="et">xxxxx</option_text> 
  <option_text lang="en">xxxxx</option_text> 
  <option_text lang="lt">xxxxx</option_text>
```

but when XML file has lines:

```
<option_price unit="LTL">1932</option_price> 
  <option_text lang="et">xxxxx</option_text> 
  <option_text lang="en-us">xxxxx</option_text> 
  <option_text lang="lt">xxxxx</option_text>
```

then something puts in "language" table strange values.

I hope I said everything necessary.

Comment: what does `$this->_get_id` do? You are probably not parsing correctly.